# How to solve Timepicker import problem on ant design 5.0.3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, antd, timepicker

I got Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'antd/lib/time-picker/style' at webpackMissingModule error after upgrading ant design to 5.0.3. How to solve this problem?

I want to solve the error that I am gettting from ant design library.

Comment: All css files have been removed in latest antd 5 version. Also time-picker is moved outside the date-picker folder. Last thing, don't use lib folder, it'll be removed in future. lib folder was added back after in 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Check out how to migrate from V4 to V5: https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5

There are even some upgrades for the `Timepicker` Component.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same issue using Antd 5.0.6.

```
import { TimePicker, Form } from 'antd'

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <Form layout='vertical'>
      <Form.Item label='Time picker'>
        <TimePicker format={'HH:mm'} />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>)
}
```

and keep getting the error

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'antd/lib/time-picker/style'

when looking into the `node_modules.antd` folder it seems that `time-picker` folder component doesn't include any style folder, but all other components have one. I'm guessing it's missing a file from moving `time-picker` outside of the `date-picker` folder since release 5.0.0.

If you copy and paste the style folder from `date-picker` into the `time-picker` folder it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

That will be the error you get if you still are importing with babel.
The fix is as described in the migration guide:

Remove babel-plugin-import from package.json and modify .babelrc:

```
"plugins": [
- ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "lib"}, "antd"],
]
```

You may not need to remove the package if you are using babel-plugin-import for something else.